# How to rename sequentially selected files with different extensions using a BAT script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-rename

I need a BAT script that renames sequentially selected files with different extensions. Also numbers from 1 to 9 should be padded with two zeroes, and those from 10 to 99 with two zeroes.

It should work like that: I select some files from Windows Explorer, then I call this script from the context menu, then it should ask me the starting number (from where the numbering begins), then it should rename the selected files sequentially.

e.g.

```
INPUT:
abc.txt
fghdhsk.jpg
khdfyl.jpg
pjdhfjshk.mp3
zhdsghjfj.png

Starting number: 2

OUTPUT:
002.txt
003.jpg
004.jpg
005.mp3
006.png
```

So far, I found this simpler script, but renames everything (not only the selected files), it doesn't ask for a starting number, and it doesn't add padded zeroes:

```
@echo off
set /p start=Starting number: 

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /r %%g in (*.*) do (call :RenameIt %%g)
goto :eof
goto :exit

:RenameIt
echo Renaming "%~nx1" to !start!%~x1
ren "%~nx1" !start!%~x1
set /a start+=1
goto :eof

:exit
exit /b
```

Anyone knows how to modify this script?

Comment: Do you want numbers like 001 002 and 098 099 ?

Comment: Yes. To be sure there are always displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this batch file:

```
@echo off
set /p "start=Starting number: "
:loop
set "num=00%start%"
set "num=%num:~-3%"
ren "%~1" "%num%%~x1"
set /a start+=1
shift
if not "%~1"=="" goto :loop
```

Comment: I missed a single % sign - test it again.

Comment: It works now, thanks a lot. Another little request: is there any way to modify it that it renames correctly even if I input numbers over 999?

As it is, if I input 1315 as starting number, it starts numbering from 315 (the 1 is ignored).

Even if it can't be done without spoiling the script, I will accept your reply as the good one anyway.

Comment: You could place `if not "%start%"=="%start:~,2%" goto :skip` after the `:loop` label and insert the new label `:skip` immediately before the `ren` line; this asks whether `%start%` holds a number with more than 2 digits and skips the prefixing of `0`(s) in case.

Comment: @AceofHz  You asked for 3 digit padding and now want to handle 4 digits - so do you want to use 4 digits all the time?  Will you ever use 5 digit numbers?